# Salesforce API Requests number keeps increasing

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

In our Salesforce account we have a limit of 20,000 API calls.

I have a script that runs every morning and that is it, it consumes about 100 API calls.

But during the day I notice that the used API calls keep rising, about 5 calls every minute.

I do have workflows and triggers.

Do these trigger API calls? I don't think so, but I can't figure out why the number of API calls called keeps rising.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any AppExchange products installed? Many 3rd Party applications that integrate with Salesforce do so using the API. Given that you are seeing an increase every 5 minutes that would indicate something that is polling the system using the API.

The most common one that I know of are marketing applications that need to stay in sync with the current contact and lead data.

Comment: Nope, no AppExhange products. The increase every 5 minutes was just a ballpark, sorry for confusion. I tried to enable debug monitoring, but that still doesn't show me API calls.

Comment: One other thing you can try then is to check the login history. Goto Setup > Administrative Setup > Manage Users > Login History. It should tell you how a user accessed Salesforce under the API Type column.